# How to prevent subview release self after call removeFromSuperview?

Tags: ios, storyboard, subview

I want to change with two subviews as button been clicked, the subview was created by StoryBoard, each subview has a button, click the button will bring another subview and hidden current one.
But I found when a subview call removeFromSuperview(), it will be release automatically, if I want to use this subview later, I need a var to point it.
Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
    var temp1: UIView?
    var temp2: UIView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        temp1 = firstView
        temp2 = secondView
        secondView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    @IBAction func moveToSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
        firstView.removeFromSuperview()
        view.insertSubview(secondView, at: 0)
        secondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    @IBAction func moveToFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {
        secondView.removeFromSuperview()
        view.insertSubview(firstView, at: 0)
        firstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Without two temp var, subview will release after removeFromSuperview, and cause next insertSubview crash because it is nil.
So, How to prevent subview auto release?
Is there another way to change between two subviews created by StoryBoard graceful?

My mistake, I didn't notice that outlet is weak, everything is reasonable, when removeFromSuperview, no strong point is left to the sub view, than it release automatically.

Comment: try to hide show your views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!` to create strong reference of the view.But as per your requirement I suggest not to remove it from the super view. Instead of that you should hide and show the views when needed as below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var firstView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    secondView.isHidden = true
}
@IBAction func moveToSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
    firstView.isHidden = true
    secondView.isHidden = false
    secondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
@IBAction func moveToFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {
    secondView.isHidden = true
    firstView.isHidden = false
    firstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two views are one upon above , having same width and same height . In viewDidLoad . first set the firstView to front and secondView to back. Once button click i bring secondView to front and firstView to back , like so on.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var firstView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: firstView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: secondView)
    }
    @IBAction func moveToSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: secondView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: firstView)
    }
    @IBAction func moveToFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: firstView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: secondView)
    }
}
```

If your two sub view's are in different position of the view. then you need to hide alternative View in respective button click

```
      class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet var firstView: UIView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            secondView.isHidden = true
            firstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        @IBAction func moveToSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
            firstView.isHidden = true
            secondView.isHidden = false
            secondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        @IBAction func moveToFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {
            secondView.isHidden = true
            firstView.isHidden = false
            firstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

 }
```

Comment: While you answer suggests a workaround, but it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: In the question it is not properly mentioned , how the views are laid on main view . So based on two scenario i wrote the answer . Thanks